# Adding a dynamic sublist to a task manager with Javascript (JQuery) or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an app that is a little like [this](http://web.koesbong.com/demo/codingtest/) (although also fairly different). In the app, you can add lists. I want to add a button with which you can add a "subtask" to one of these tasks; this subtask(s) would be indented, and the indentation would be accessible via some sort of small button or something of the sort to the left of the parent class. How do you achieve something like this?

I use this to add elements into the list:

```
// Add todo
    $form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.publish('/add/', []);
    });
```

and I want to be able to add nested lists under it. I've tried using  tags, but that doesn't seem to work; additionally, I'm not sure how to make said nested list accessible via button.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You have to show an attempt and ask questions about any problems you encounter.

Comment: Got it, should I add that code to the question? I'm new to this site.

Comment: If you're asking about markup, just used nested `<ul>`s. If you're having a specific problem, update your question with code and an explanation of what you've tried.

Comment: Your questions (in any forum) should always include: what you have tried (your code, condensed to only the problem area), expected behavior, actual behavior and steps to reproduce.